# i386. 32-bit architectures are not supported when deployment target is 11

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I customized an official Xamarin example project around half a year ago and used it as a template and built my app around it.

When I wanted to build it in Release Mode, I got the error

```
Invalid architecture: i386. 32-bit architectures are not supported when deployment target is 11
```

My iOS Build settings were:

```
iOS Build
Target OS: Default (if I click the combobox, VS2017 would also let me choose 11.1 instead)
Supported architecture: i386 + x86_64
```

I created a new Xamarin PCL project in VS2017 to see what the standard settings would be for an iOS build.

Those were:

```
iOS Build
Target OS: 10.1
Supported architecture: i386 + x86_64
```

I wonder if the error that I'm getting is related to the iOS Build settings at all, and if yes, what I should choose and what I should target.

As written below, VS2017 wouldn't let me select "10.1" in my original project, it would only allow me "Default" or "11.1".

Comment: iOS11 now requires that all apps are 64 bit

Comment: @Jason What should I chose now? I mean I can only chose iOS11 now in my project. Should I select Architecture x86_64 (I'm confused by the name though as you said iOS11 doesn't support x864)? Obviously i386 is x86, so it wouldn't work. x86_64 is the only option that I can choose, right?

Comment: yes, that is the 64 bit version of x86, but that is only necessary for simulator builds.  Actual devices builds are ARM, not x86

Answer (score 0):

"32-bit architectures are not supported" may even appear if a 32-bit ARM architecture ist selected when using 11er SDK and 11er minimum deployment target.

To be able to build for architectures ARMv7s + ARM64 (in project options), set the minimum deployment target in Info.plist to 9.1 for example. In project options also make sure to select 'Link framework SDKs only'.